# Problem booting ubuntu 20.04

Tags: boot

I run a dual-boot win 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 on my pc, boots on legacy mode. Now Im trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 on a flash disk on the same machine for better performance. Ive created a Fat32 partition on the drive, and choose "something else" when installing Ubuntu on the other (ext4) partition of the drive. installation is complete but EFI (fat32) partition on the drive is empty and I can't boot to the drive.
I understand that ubuntu tries to install the grub on the HDD's first partition, but since win 10 boots in legacy, there is no EFI/boot and EFI/ubuntu on my hdd to copy into the drive.
is there a work-around to get the pc to boot into flash drive?
ps: I've tried to grub-install through chroot on live usb, to no avail (efi partition still empty)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have created the USB drive in an incorrect way. To create a bootable USB drive, follow the steps outlined here:  https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview

Comment: I dont want to create a bootable live usb, I want to install a full installation on a usb drive